# Como insertar un contar que enumere mi tabla

Tags: sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo esta consulta, lo que quiero es insertar un campo que se llame Ranking que enumero del 1,2,...20.

```
    SELECT TOP 20 
ISNULL(Nombre_Area,'Otras Areas') AS Area, count(*) AS #Tickets
FROM tickets_noviembre 
GROUP BY Nombre_Area 
ORDER BY #Tickets DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes añadir la columna con números como quieres utilizando la función [ROW_NUMBER()](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) que básicamente lo que hace es enumerar las filas de tu resultado, algo así:

```
    SELECT TOP 20 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Nombre_Area ASC) AS Ranking, 
            Nombre_Area, 
            count(*) AS Total
    FROM tickets_noviembre 
    GROUP BY Nombre_Area 
    ORDER BY Total DESC
```

Comment: SELECT TOP 20 
ISNULL(Nombre_Area,'Otras Areas') AS Area, count(*) AS #Tickets
FROM tickets_noviembre 
GROUP BY Nombre_Area 
ORDER BY #Tickets DESC

Comment: Y si fuera esa la consulta ?

Comment: Puedes sustituir el nombre de la columna despues del ORDER BY por (SELECT NULL).

Answer (score 0):

Prueba lo siguiente:
- Se inserta tu registro con una nueva columna identity en una tabla temporal y luego muestras la tabla temporal

```
SELECT TOP 20 identity(int, 1,1) AS [Enumeracion],
ISNULL(Nombre_Area,'Otras Areas') AS Area,
 count(*) AS 'Tickets' into #temp
FROM tickets_noviembre 
GROUP BY Nombre_Area 
ORDER BY 3 DESC


select * from #temp

--drop table #temp --Si esque deseas luego borrar la tabla temporal-
```

Answer (score 0):

Con `ROW_NUMBER()` puedes hacer fácilmente un ranking

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Total DESC) as RANKING
, Nombre_Area, Total
FROM (SELECT TOP 20 Nombre_Area, count(*) AS Total
      FROM tickets_noviembre 
      GROUP BY Nombre_Area 
      ORDER BY Total DESC
) b
```

Comment: SELECT TOP 20 
ISNULL(Nombre_Area,'Otras Areas') AS Area, count(*) AS #Tickets
FROM tickets_noviembre 
GROUP BY Nombre_Area 
ORDER BY #Tickets DESC